# PHP .htaccess Using Variables as folders/files?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web

So I have a solution to my initial issue, however I don't think this is very efficient or secure.

In short, I want to redirect users who type example.com/[random 9 Alpha-Numeric code] to example.com/claim.php while still using their entered url.

And I want to redirect example.com/[random 4 Alpha-Numeric code] to example.com/referral.php

My .htaccess file contains:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./claim.php?code=$1
```

I have thought about redirecting all codes to a single php file and then choosing where to go, but I feel there is a better way.

I am not looking for someone to write me anything, I just some need someone to direct me towards an answer with what I need to look up.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(\w{9})$ ./claim.php?code=$1` and `RewriteRule ^(\w{4})$ ./referral.php?code=$1`

Comment: That is exactly what I need, but do you have a useful link that could give me further information about RewriteRule and what I can do with the .htaccess?

Comment: Its basically just regular expressions, you can create whatever rules you want using regular expressions. Practice your regexs on https://www.regex101.com.